# What are the two dimensions of relativity that are added to string theory?

Tags: string-theory, relativity, spacetime-dimensions, quantum-anomalies

Based on the Ramanujam's modular functions, somehow these magic numbers 10 and 26 spacetime dimensions appear in string theory. The dimensions can be viewed as 8 + 2 and 24 + 2. The number 2 is added due to relativity. But what are these two dimensions? Or this 2 represents something different?

Comment: These aren't two dimensions; these are two *possible numbers of dimensions*. In other words, they are two possibilities for the number of dimensions.

Comment: @HDE226868 Could you kindly explain a little further? What are the two Possibilities of dimensions? Is it 0 or some n number of dimensions?

Comment: I think that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Number_of_dimensions) may help you better than I can.

Comment: What does this bit mean: "They can be generalized as 8 ( 8 + 2). 2 is added due to relativity."?

Comment: @innisfree in this article http://kairos.laetusinpraesens.org/taote5_0_h_7 the author says "8+2 or 10 [adding two dimensions for the case of relativistic theory]"

Comment: 26 is not an option, since that's the choice for bosonic string theory, which doesn't incorporate fermions. Also, one shouldn't really think of the dimension having to be fixed for the theory to be consistent - it's not very enlightening. What we want is the central charge to vanish to get rid of the trace anomaly, which eventually leads to $D=26$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, the $1+1=2$ extra dimensions of spacetime can (in an appropriate gauge) be viewed as a longitudinal spatial direction and a temporal direction. This makes sense because of Minkowski signature of spacetime.

The point is that the physical modes of the string can be identified with the 24 (8) transversal directions of the critical bosonic (super) string, respectively. This splitting of spacetime is the starting point of [light-cone quantization](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=light+cone+quantization+string+theory) of string theory. The specific spacetime dimension is needed to cancel the [conformal anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_anomaly).

Comment: This is similar to d.o.f. of a photon. A photon has 4 d.o.f in 4-d space-time, but only 2 physical after 2 removed by gauge symmetry, Ramanujam's modular functions give the physical, vibrating d.o.f. of the string, then we add 2 for the gauge symmetry to get them all.

Comment: @innisfree: I agree.